# MudBlazor MudNumericField Call a function on oninput

Tags: blazor, mudblazor

```
<MudNumericField Value=@model.Amt Label="Concession Amount" @oninput="FunctionNAME" For="@(() => model.Amt)" />
```

THIS FUNCTION IS REQUIRED WHEN i TYPE ANY NUMERIC KEY from Keyboard

```
  public async Task FunctionNAME(ChangeEventArgs e)
  {
      //CALLING THIS FUNCTION
  }
```

UNABLE TO CALL THIS FUNCTION

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `ValueChanged` EventCallback instead of `@oninput`.

And if you need to trigger the method on each keypress then you set `Immediate="true"` for `MudNumericField`

```
<MudNumericField Value=@model.Amt ValueChanged="(double newValue)=>FunctionNAME(newValue)" Immediate="true" Label="Concession Amount" For="@(() => model.Amt)"/>

public async Task FunctionNAME(double newValue) // your model.Amt type
{
    //CALLING THIS FUNCTION
    model.Amt = newValue
}
```

Comment: This word for me